# CLion build process does not start make install

Tags: clion

I have some libraries that I install using make install in a specific folder. However, when I run ( Alt Shift F10 ), it only does the make and not the make install.

Is there any way I can force CLion to do a make install before it runs the binary.

Comment: Cmake should add the necessary rpath information to be able to run the binary. Do you load the library with dlopen() or how do you link?

Comment: @arved : u misunderstood. I meant, that when you run a project, then it first does a build ( make ) and then runs the binary.. All is good here. However, I want clion to do a make install ( copy all libraries to a folder )  after the make too, before running the binary.

Comment: @oLen :  Thank you.. thats what I was indeed looking for.

Comment: Unfrotunately, the answer mentioned in the other thread, shows a method to create a new target and does not solve the problem mentioned.